# Python - how to build a multi-list for loop?

Tags: python, for-loop

At my application, I use FFmpeg to pack videos for web delivery in HLS format.
During development, I wrote the following for loop in order to create a master.m3u8 playlist. Basically, this is working fine, except of one thing I currently don't understand. How can I make this work exactly the same way if I have multiple video jobs. Meaning, I have one job at position [0] and a second one at [1] ?

```
for agroup_name, agroup in a_groups.items():
    streaminf = f'#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH={int(job["config"]["output_options"]["stream_bandwidth_multiplier"] * (job["video"][0]["bitrate"] + max(audio["bitrate"] for audio in agroup)))}'
    streaminf += f',RESOLUTION={str(job["video"][0]["width"])}x{str(job["video"][0]["height"])}'
    streaminf += f',CODECS="{",".join([job["video"][0]["hls"]["codec"], *set(map(lambda x: x["hls"]["codec"], agroup))])}"'
    streaminf += f',AUDIO="{agroup_name}"'

    if has_subtitles:
        # We expect only one subtitle group -> Will always be [0]
        subtitle_group_name = list(s_groups.values())[0][0]
        streaminf += f',SUBTITLES="{build_groupname(subtitle_group_name["hls"]["group_id"][0], "subtitle")}"'

    write_file_newlines(file, [
        streaminf,
        build_name(job["video"][0]) + "/master.m3u8",
        ""
    ])
```

Currently, the output look like this:

```
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=12238336,RESOLUTION=3840x1606,CODECS="avc1.640033,ac-3",AUDIO="a-0",SUBTITLES="s-0"
v-h264/master.m3u8

#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=11815936,RESOLUTION=3840x1606,CODECS="avc1.640033,mp4a.40.2",AUDIO="a-1",SUBTITLES="s-0"
v-h264/master.m3u8
```

But in the end it has to look like this. All this information is packed in the video job element:

```
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=12238336,RESOLUTION=3840x1606,CODECS="avc1.640033,ac-3",AUDIO="a-0",SUBTITLES="s-0"
v-h264/master.m3u8

#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=11815936,RESOLUTION=3840x1606,CODECS="avc1.640033,mp4a.40.2",AUDIO="a-1",SUBTITLES="s-0"
v-h264/master.m3u8

#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=15238336,RESOLUTION=3840x1606,CODECS="hev1.1.6.L93.B0,ac-3",AUDIO="a-0",SUBTITLES="s-0"
v-hevc/master.m3u8

#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=14815936,RESOLUTION=3840x1606,CODECS="hev1.1.6.L93.B0,mp4a.40.2",AUDIO="a-1",SUBTITLES="s-0"
v-hevc/master.m3u8
```

So I somehow need to loop over the jobs, but this total makes my mind suffer ^^

Thanks in advance

Comment: you should show what data you have in variable. If `position [0]` means `job["video"][0]` and `position [1]` means `job["video"][1]` then you should use outer `for`-loop with `for item in job['video']:` and later use `item` instead of `job["video"][0]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `position [0]` means `job["video"][0]` and `position [1]` means `job["video"][1]` then you should use outer `for`-loop with `for item in job['video']:` and later use `item` instead of `job["video"][0]`

Something like this:

```
for item in job['video']:

    for agroup_name, agroup in a_groups.items():
        streaminf = f'#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH={int(job["config"]["output_options"]["stream_bandwidth_multiplier"] * (item["bitrate"] + max(audio["bitrate"] for audio in agroup)))}'
        streaminf += f',RESOLUTION={item["width"]}x{item["height"]}'
        streaminf += f',CODECS="{",".join([item["hls"]["codec"], *set(map(lambda x: x["hls"]["codec"], agroup))])}"'
        streaminf += f',AUDIO="{agroup_name}"'
    
        if has_subtitles:
            # We expect only one subtitle group -> Will always be [0]
            subtitle_group_name = list(s_groups.values())[0][0]
            streaminf += f',SUBTITLES="{build_groupname(subtitle_group_name["hls"]["group_id"][0], "subtitle")}"'
    
        write_file_newlines(file, [
            streaminf,
            build_name(item) + "/master.m3u8",
            ""
        ])
```

---

If you use `[0]` with other variables then you may need `for i in range(len(job['video'])):`  and later use `[i]` in `job['video'][i]` and `other_variable[i]`

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, seems to work fine now! but when using for i in range ...
You will get back Class 'int' does not define '__getitem__', so the '[]' operator cannot be used on its instances.

Comment: I have no idea why you get this error - it seems you use `[i]` in wrong place - it has to be `job['video'][i]` . And if you have to use it with another variable then you have to put `[i]` in place of `[0]`

Comment: Indeed xD, damn. Sorry my mistake. Really, I'm kinda done for today. Again thanks for your help.